# OpenID Connect use case

Tags: jwt, openid-connect

Recently I've discovered OpenID Connect standard and now I'm struggling with figuring out the right way to use it.

So let's say I'm building a pretty standard web app which must have a notion of authenticated user. So my first intent is to build a local DB with user table, containing user id, email, first & last name, password, salt etc.
This means I need to implement all the relevant features like sign up, sign in, change/forget password etc.

Instead of doing this I opt for using OpenID connect and leverage user information stored elsewhere (for example at Google).

Then I can perform the usual OAuth2 magic to redirect user, ask for consent and so on.

Starting from this point I'm kind of loosing the track. After Google (or whatever AS) returned to my backend app ID token with basic user info (email, name, phone)
what do I do with it? Shall I still have a local user DB (without password) populated from these fields? In this case OpenID Connect is just a fancy automatic sign-up procedure? And what about sessions and log-outs, what if user changes his phone on the Google site while I still have it saved the old version?

I was reading a lot of OpenID Connect articles on the web but they all seem to describe basic flows on getting the token, so I'm confused about further stages.

I'd really appreciate any hints / advices on this problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would agree with you that the most interesting aspect of these modern authentication schemes is that you easily delegate authentication to a third-party provider and not be burdened with having to write and support all that boilerplate, but highly sensitive code around managing user identities.

In relation to your, what happens next questions lets approach them one by one; I'll try not to start every answer with it depends.

---

<sup>**Q1**</sup>*Shall I still have a local user DB (without password) populated from these fields?*

It depends, if your application does not need to know about user information when the user is not online interacting with the application then you can get away with almost not having to store anything. At most you want to store a unique user identifier to data that the user creates.

On the other hand, if your application notifies the user by email when something (really) interesting happens then you need to store the user email on your database.

---

<sup>**Q2**</sup>*(If I need to duplicate almost all the information in my database is) OpenID Connect just a fancy automatic sign-up procedure?*

Kind of, just by being a standard that allows you to delegate your application authentication to a third-party you already gained massive benefits from its existence. Authentication is not trivial, if you can offload that to someone else, do it. By doing this you're also doing the end user a favor, because (depending on the popularity of the provider you choose) he can now login into your application without having to remember yet another set of credentials.

---

<sup>**Q3**</sup>*What about sessions and log-outs?*

Here there are no substantial changes if you want an independent session. Before your application would validate credentials and start a session, now it will validate a token that might be provided by a third-party and then start a session. Logout would just end your session.

If you want a synced session, so that the user is only active in your application while he also has a session in the third-party provider then you have more work to do. See, if you haven't done it already, [OpenID Connect Session Management 1.0](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html) for more information.

---

<sup>**Q4**</sup>*What if user changes his phone on the Google site while I still have it saved the old version?*

That's a non issue, because if you were not using OpenID Connect and had to manage application-specific user identities, you would have the same problem. The user would change their phone on Google and unless he also proactively changed the phone in your app it would be outdated.

As *fiddur* pointed out, there's also the possibility of proactively checking with the provider if there's updated information. This is something that most provider support and has the side-benefit that can also provide a good user experience for the end user.

---

**In conclusion**, if you have the opportunity to delegate authentication to an external provider please do so. Implementing your own custom authentication or even establishing yourself as an authentication provider complying with all the available standards is a very time consuming challenge, riddled with security pitfalls.

If you are thinking that you need to have better control of the authentication process than what a social authentication provider would give you, there's still the option of going with a more flexible provider, [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) comes to mind, but I'm biased **(** I'm an Auth0 engineer **)**. This type of option will give you more control while still taking the burden of implementing authentication standards of your back.

Comment: Q2: It also gives the user a single sign on opportunity, especially if more providers were to offer OpenID Connect Dynamic Registration as well.

Comment: Q4: There's also the option of re-checking the userinfo regularly from the provider, so the user won't have to update the same info on all sites.

Comment: @fiddur, that's true, there are significant benefits for the end user. I'll update those two points to mention the gains from the user perspective. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you guys, now it makes much more sense. I guess I just wasn't looking at this from the right angle.